# Matching word when not followed by number or space+number

Tags: c, regex

I wanna match "on" as long as it's not followed by a number or a space+number - without using negative lookaheads (because as far as I can tell, C doesn't support this - please correct me if I'm wrong).

Thanks!

Comment: C? C doesn't have a standard regex library.

Comment: The point (I suspect) is that an answer with a regex pattern is probably not useful without some regex library.  From the wording of the question, it doesn't sound like you are using a regex library.  Are you asking for a regex pattern?

Comment: I really should have dropped the C-tag. =) I'm using regex.h (thought that was obvious enough..).

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <regex.h>
regex_t re;
/* regcomp(&re, "on([^ ]| [^[:digit:]])", REG_EXTENDED); */ // thanks sln :)
regcomp(&re, "on ?[^ 0-9]", REG_EXTENDED);
```

Comment: Not space will match a digit so if looking for a positive match, on9 will match when it probably shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a matcher in C but without regex, then you might want to take a look at `isspace()`, `isdigit()` and `isalpha()` in *ctype.h*

Answer (score 0):

You want to match a string that has your conditions in it?

edit - didn't read ? very well

edit - Ok, here ya go buddy

`/on([^\d ]|[ ](\D|$)|$)/`

Test case:

```
use strict; use warnings;

my @samps = (
' on',
' on9',
' on ',
' on 5',
' on  7',
' on p',
' on6 ',
);

for (@samps) {
   if ( /on([^\d ]|[ ](\D|$)|$)/ ) { 
         print "matched '$_'\n";
   }
   else {
         print "'$_' failed\n";
   }      
}
```

Output

```
matched ' on'
' on9' failed
matched ' on '
' on 5' failed
matched ' on  7'
matched ' on p'
' on6 ' failed
```